# Minus paddingTop on Android ListView, is it possible?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have top margin of `30dp` inside some of my list view items (including always the first one). However I don't want this top margin on my first list view item.

I have tried offsetting this by adding the following to the `ListView`

```
   android:paddingTop="-30dp"
```

However, it doesn't seem to have any effect and the first list view item is still 30dp below the top edge of the list view.

**Is there a way of getting minus top padding to work on an Android ListView?**

**XML**

```
<ListView    
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"          
  android:divider="@null"          
  android:dividerHeight="0dp"          
  android:paddingTop="-30dp"          
  android:layout_height="match_parent"          
  android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Then some of the  list view items content is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"     
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
  android:layout_width="match_parent"/
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
  <!--other content here-->
</LinearLayout>
```

The first list view item always uses the above template and im trying to offset that 30dp top margin.

Comment: can you show your xml ?

Comment: post your xml, check for any padding is set

Comment: @subspider xml of listview and lsit view item template added.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" in your linear layout, so that you'll have the top of list without any margin but between list items still with margin. Does it look like what you want? Because minus padding is normally possible but in your case its overridden by the margin in list items.

Comment: I cant do that because I don't always want bottom margin of 30. i.e. of I could target the last list view item before the item that I want top margin on then I could give that one bottom margin of 30. but I cant do that just in the xml

Comment: are you saying if I remove that top margin off the linearlayout (list item) then the minus padding top on the listview will have an effect? because ive just tried that and the padding top still has no effect

Comment: Hmm you're right, minus values are only possible in margins. In padding they are ineffective.

Comment: so the answer to my question is no. is it documented anywhere that minus padding on list views are ineffective? or do you just know from experience?

Comment: Not especially in list view, I think it is in general. I haven't read in the documentation, I tried it. I always use minus margins and I thought the same would work with paddings. But it didn't work for a button I tried, where minus margin worked.